# How can I show related posts from multiple separate installations

Tags: database, blog

Say I have three sites, abc.com, def.com and xyz.com. All the three sites are different wordpress installations and different databases. Now in story page I want that related articles should come from all the three sites. Is this possible from any plugin or any custom code?

I am not talking about multisite. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: maybe you could have some fun with [new JSON apis](http://wptavern.com/json-rest-api-slated-for-wordpress-4-1-release)

Answer (score 0):

You would have different choices. I encourage you to use RSS. There are a lot of resources on that, you could benefit from the power of RSS which is pretty well implemented in wordpress. Or just like I said in comment look into th new JSON APIs.

So basically look for codes that take the RSS or JSON feeds and convert them into something you could use e.g posts.

Comment: Yes I am also thinking of RSS. But RSS gives latest post. How can I use logic for related articles. Also this is just an example. I am not havng 3 blogs. I am having network of around 25 blogs.

Answer (score -3):

3 blog because your blog is different 3 without trang
therefore to perform the display of related posts will relatively complex
Case 1: If 3 blog on the same server, you can make it easier
Case 2: If 3 blog located on different servers, you'll first need to have access to the mysql server between 3 blog
Do you understand what I mean?
If you already know, so now I presume that you have access mysql server of 3 blog
ok.
I will guide you to query the data using mysql fulltext search
suppose, I'm in the first blog is abc.com
I now want to display related posts from def.com
You need to connect to the 2nd blog def.com

```
mysql_connect ($ server, $ user, $ password);
mysql_select_db ($ data_def);
$ Sql ​​= "SELECT * FROM {$ wpdb-> prefix} posts WHERE MATCH (POST_TITLE) AGAINST ($ title);"
$ Result = mysql_query ($ sql) or die (mysql_error ());
while ($ row = mysql_fetch_array ($ result)) {
$ Id = $ row ['ID'];
$ Title = $ row ['POST_TITLE'];
...
}
```

Just as simple as that, but there are things you have to access mysql server between 3 blog

Wish you success!

Comment: `mysql_connect()`? Really? Use WordPress’ database API.

Comment: not to mention it would just fail